# Is there any other scenario of TCP segment window size equal 0?

Tags: tcp

Is there any other scenario of window size equal 0?

in my impression, if the window_size == 0, there have two cases:

```
1.the TCP acceptance area is full, then send window_size = 0
2.send RST package, the window_size = 0
```

is there any other scenario of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A receive window size of zero signals *send no more data* - when the receiver is busy processing, buffers are filled or simply there's no data currently required (think of video streaming).

Comment: Other than RST packages that actively set window size to 0, what other types of packages do that?

Comment: Usually ACK segments. Note that RST aborts a socket connection - it's usually closed by FIN (which may also set the window to 0).